# Keras Variational Autoencoders implementation displays wrong sum of reconstruction and KL loss

Tags: keras

I am implementing the Keras Variational Autoencoder (https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/). During the training process, the total loss printed is not the sum of the reconstruction loss and the kl loss terms as it should be. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

I suspect that the issue is related with the loss trackers but I have no idea how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code mentioned in your question the loss shown in during training is the total loss because you return the total loss in the training step. However if you have changed something you should attach your code (in git please :) and show the losses during training.

Comment: The point is that the total loss is defined as the sum of the reconstruction loss and the kl loss. However during the training process the total loss printed is not the sum of the reconstruction and kl losses printed. The code is exactly the keras implementation.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your training output? On the website you have linked the total loss is clearly the wheighted sum of the two losses. 
Another and imo better option is to log your losses with [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard). There you can make a writer, add the partial losses you want and even upload it to the cloud. It's also convienient when working on a cluster later on.

Comment: What do you mean with weighted sum? Where are the weights introduced? Because I should expect to obtain simply loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss

Comment: Try following [these instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/Regularizer) to find out if you have some regularization in one of your layers. You can print it out with `tf.math.reduce_sum(layer.losses)`. Regularization terms would not be applied to intermediate losses. This may be a clou.